# Can not load Json model in the Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I want to import a simple Json model into the Three.js scene.

http://kripken.github.io/ammo.js/examples/webgl_demo_softbody_volume/index.html

After creating lights in the scene, I want to load json model.

`var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();`

```
jsonLoader.load('models/toy.json', addToytoScn);

function addToytoScn(geometry, material) {
    var toyMtl = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material);
    var toyMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, toyMtl);

    scene.add(toyMesh );
}
```

but I got an error...  I do not understand what happened in my case....

```
TypeError: n is undefined

THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.parse/<()           three.min.js:391
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.parse()             three.min.js:391
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.load/<()            three.min.js:390
THREE.XHRLoader.prototype.load/<()             three.min.js:383
```

[I export a Json model from Blender.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbpQ1.jpg)

when I set  Type:Buffergeometry.   >>   I got  error.

when I set  Type:Geometry.   >>   I can import the json model successfully.

But I need to export Buffergeometry type model  in this case.....

Comment: I think that I can use the method.

var sphereGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(  "put geometry here"  );

How can I put in only "geometry" of the 'toyMesh'

Comment: I have solved this problem!